# How to do `Hash` to a unit struct in rust?

Tags: hash, equality, rust

I'd like to implement a kind of *thing* which can be uniquely identified, besides, it contains no other fields. It 's kinds of like `BasicObject` in ruby, or `Object` in java.

I have added a `PartialEq` trait.

```
struct Thing;
impl PartialEq for Thing {
  fn eq(&self, other: &Thing) -> bool {
    unsafe {
      self as *const Thing == other as *const Thing
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to allow that it can be hashed, and the question is how could I implement [Hash](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) trait for a unit struct which has no fileds ? Or, should I add some kind of `object_id` to it ?

Comment: How do you plan to use `Thing` here? You do need some data somewhere unless you always want to return the same hash every time.

Comment: @Dogbert I just want to create something that can uniquely identify itself. If you create one instance `a` of `Thing`, then `b`, then `c`, and so forth, then `a` should not be equal to any other instance of `Thing` except itself. If this can be implemented, I think it should be hashed using its identity too.

Comment: It's very weird to rely on object identity in Rust (i.e. it's memory location), since moving it around on the stack can change the location. An object id field that is e.g. randomly initialised, or initialised via an global [atomic counter](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUint.html#method.fetch_add) would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on pointer address to determine for sure unicity of unit structs in Rust, for example the following code will print two times the same address:

```
struct Foo;

fn main() {
    let x = Foo;
    let y = Foo;
    println!("{}", &x as *const _);
    println!("{}", &y as *const _);
}
```

You need to have them occupy at least one byte in memory, for example by giving them a field that you never use :

```
struct Thing {
    x: u8;
}

impl Thing {
    fn new() -> Thing {
        Thing { x: 0u8 }
    }
}
```

Then, a simple way would be to continue on the same track as you are going, and using the address of your objects in memory as a base value for the Hash :

```
use std::hash::{hash,Hash};
use std::hash::sip::SipState;

struct Thing;

impl Hash for Thing {
    fn hash(&self, state: &mut SipState) {
        let addr = self as *const Thing as u64;
        addr.hash(state);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Thing;
    println!("{}", hash(&f));
}
```

Note : casting `&Thing` to `*const Thing` (and then to `u64`) is not unsafe, so you don't need the `unsafe{}` block in your implementation of PartialEq.

Comment: "Unit structs are not instantiated and stored in memory by Rust, and in this state, all you instances of Thing will be equal", this isn't true, unit structs [do have distinct addresses](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=struct%20Foo%3B%0A%0A%23%5Binline%28never%29%5D%0Afn%20bar%28%29%20{%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20Foo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22{}%22%2C%20%26x%20as%20*const%20_%29%3B%0A}%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20{%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20Foo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22{}%22%2C%20%26y%20as%20*const%20_%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20bar%28%29%3B%0A}). (That said...

Comment: ... they can easily behave in unexpected ways, due to being zero-sized, so it's probably best not to rely on it.)

Comment: @dbaupp Yeah, but if you instantiate one two times in the same scope, they'll have the same address...

Comment: True enough, but that's just an implementation detail, the compiler is perfectly well allowed to give them different addresses (that is, your new phrasing as "cannot rely" is good).

Comment: Using the address may not be the right solution, because [the address can change if you move the object](http://is.gd/TvT60v).